# wordpress not generate thumnails for mp4 videos

Tags: media-library

i have wordpress installed v4.6 , when i upload videos in media manager it cant generate thumbnails for video, am uploading mp4 videos.

so any idea how to add/configure ffmpeg library for wordpress.

on my Debian 8 server have ffmpeg installed in

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg
```

also which wordpress file is responsible for file uploading so that i may make changes to it. 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can output them on the front end using custom fields like this:

```
printf( '<a href="%s"><img src="%s" /></a>', get_post_meta( get_the_id(),'video_url', true ), the_post_thumbnail_url() );
```

Or this if you want to use a different image for your video thumbnail

```
printf( '<a href="%s"><img src="%s" /></a>', get_post_meta( get_the_id(),'video_url', true ), get_post_meta( get_the_id(),'video_img', true ) );
```

Comment: i cant understated !!

Comment: Thus relates to the output of the featured image in replace of the video thumbnail. Add the video URL to the custom field named video_url and it will link the post thumbnail to your video which you can display anywhere. Otherwise use a variable equal to another custom field if you want to use a different image as your video thumbnail. Assumes usage on the front end only, not in the Media Library.